# Am I using too many triggers within mySQL database?

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

I had a problem within my database where clients would update their information on the website, and the update would overwrite their original information in the database. To have a record of the clients previous information and when they updated it to the 'new' information, I have created a trigger for the specific database. 
Example:

```
CREATE TRIGGER clientstatustrigger AFTER UPDATE ON clientstatus
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO clientstatusrecord SET id = NEW.id, oldstatus = OLD.status, newstatus = NEW.status, timechanged = NOW();
END;
```

It has worked really great so far! However, I will need to implement this technique for a lot of tables. I will be creating a "record" table for each table I need to track the changes within, and one trigger for those tables. My question is, is this too many triggers? Will I see disadvantages in the future? I understand triggers are hard to debug since people forget they are there, but is there reason for me to change this system? If so, what do you recommend?

Comment: This is hard for anybody to answer until you give some likely stats for your updates - how big, how many, how frequent etc.

Comment: If you have to ask, the answer is probably "yes"